# I am implementing an algorithm to test the validitiy of a credit card in java

Tags: java

I used `Luhn algorithm` but, for some reason all of the card numbers I try it always displays that the card number is valid even if its not.

This is my code so far I believe the issue is with the `toString` method but I have no idea on how to fix it. Please help!

```
public class CreditCard 
    {
        private String number;
        private String result;
        private int sum = 0;
        private int n = 0;
        private boolean value = true;
        private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        private String word = builder.toString();

        public CreditCard(String number)
        {
            this.number = number;
        }


        public String toString()
        {

            for(int x = 0; x < number.length(); x++)
            {
                char c = number.charAt(x);
                if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                    builder.append(c);
                }

            }
            String result = builder.toString() + " was issued by " + getIssuer();
            if(isValid())
                result += " and is valid.";
            else
                result += " and is not valid.";
            return result;
        }
        public String getIssuer()
        { 
            if(builder.length() == 13 && builder.substring(0, 1).equals("4") )
                result = "VISA";

            else if(builder.length() == 14)
            {
                if(builder.substring(0, 2).equals("36") || builder.substring(0, 2).equals("38")
                        || builder.substring(0, 3).equals("300") || builder.substring(0, 3).equals("301")
                        || builder.substring(0, 3).equals("302") || builder.substring(0, 3).equals("303")
                        || builder.substring(0, 3).equals("304") || builder.substring(0, 3).equals("305"))
                result = "Diner's Club";
                else
                    result = "Unknown";
            }

            else if(builder.length() == 15)
                {
                    if(builder.substring(0, 2).equals("34") || builder.substring(0, 2).equals("37"))
                    result = "American Express";
                    else
                        result = "Unknown";
                }

            else if(builder.length() == 16)         
                    {
                        if(builder.substring(0, 2).equals("51") || builder.substring(0, 2).equals("52") 
                                || builder.substring(0, 2).equals("53") || builder.substring(0, 2).equals("54") 
                                || builder.substring(0, 2).equals("55"))
                        {
                            result = "MasterCard";
                        }
                        else if(builder.substring(0, 4).equals("6011"))
                        {
                            result = "Discover";
                        }
                        else if(builder.substring(0, 1).equals("4"))
                        {
                            result = "VISA";
                        }
                        else
                            result = "Unknown";
                    }
            else
                result = "Unknown";

            return result;
        }

        public boolean isValid()
        {
            if(word.length() % 2 == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
                {
                    char c = word.charAt(i);

                    int num = Character.getNumericValue(c);

                    if(i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        n = num * 2;
                        if(n > 9)
                        {
                            n -=9; 
                        }
                        sum +=n;
                    }
                    else
                        sum+= num;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++)
                {
                    char c = word.charAt(x);

                    int num = Character.getNumericValue(c);

                    if(x % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        n = num * 2;
                        if(n > 9)
                        {
                            n -=9; 
                        }
                        sum +=n;
                    }
                    else
                        sum += num;
                }
            }
                if(sum % 10 == 0)
                    value = true;
                else                
                    value = false;

                return value;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to revise your method, I would put an arguments into getIssuer and isValid method. These method are public and they could be called from outside of the class and they return something, which is not correct.
If not possible, then they have to use number instance variable.

The code returns wrong results, because you are not setting the value of word variable, it is null.

Comment: btw, quick search gave the java method which implemented Luhn algorithm https://github.com/jduke32/gnuc-credit-card-checker/blob/master/CCCheckerPro/src/com/gnuc/java/ccc/Luhn.java